# Herencia y polimorfismo c++

Tags: c++

Si tengo una clase **abuelo** que a su vez tiene dos hijos (**padre** y **tio**), y **padre** tiene a su vez dos clases **hijo1** e **hijo2**, es posible definir un método en **padre**, tal que pueda ser usada por sus hijos aunque se hayan definido como Abuelo* objeto1 = new Hijo1(); ? O todos los métodos que quiera usar en los hijos los tengo que declarar como virtuales puros en la clase abuelo?

Comment: Si quieres usar un puntero a `abuelo`, por fuerza tendrás que declarar las funciones-miembro como virtuales dentro de abuelo; o bien usar RTTI para obtener la clase real y *castear* tu puntero.

Comment: También puedes usar métodos mas ... *exóticos*, como definir punteros a funciones-miembro y establecerlos en las clases hijas ... pero no lo recomiendo salvo que estés **muy mucho** seguro de lo que estás haciendo.